# Node.js scaling out on Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, scale

I have deployed a Node web app on Azure, everything was ok until i wanted to scale out.

Before scaling, I have an average response for a single event around 1500ms, which is acceptable. But the moment, i  scale out to more than 1 instance the same single event response time goes to 5-6k ms. Am i missing something fundamental here or is this something normal?

Comment: This is highly dependent on your architecture -- You need to define this more in your question otherwise you'll just be playing 20 questions.

Comment: It's very simplistic. An event is incoming, some extrernal APIs called and then some calculations, finally a response is returned to the user.
I have noticed that the calculations are becoming a lot slower. Was that helpful? :/

Comment: Does the latency continue to triple every time you add a node?

Comment: More or less, on 2 instances looks like 3-4k ms and seems to plateau at 4-5 instances 6-7k ms

Comment: Is this issue occurs on the every request, or it's an average latency as the result of some performance test tools? If so, it could be some resource competitions during the several requests being processed at the same time in your instances.

Comment: Hey @GaryLiu-MSFT, thanks for reaching out. I haven't gotten to the point of using any performance test. I have observed significant increase on average response and higher computation time that almost doubles for each new node instance i provision.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexandros, If you have scaled-out your app to more than one instance. You can turn-off session affinity which might help overload issues. Could you please try to disable ARR affinity setting?

1.Login to the Azure portal

2.Browse App Services and select your web application.

3.Click on Settings->Application Settings.

4.Find ARR affinity setting under General Settings and click on Off

Please try to check this site and use browser debugger to see ARRAffinity cookie.

Comment: Hi there, yes i have scaled out to more than one instance, after some tries i did turned off ARR affinity. Latency seemed to improved but not significantly, any other suggestion?

Comment: @AlexandrosMylonas, since this issue is a bit hard to reproduce on our side, could you please share the web app's info with us via leveraging the approach that pointed out at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly?Looking forward to having your feedback.

Comment: Following the instructions i setup  http://dummy-webapp.azurewebsites.net and there are multiple applications in this service that i am interested but mostly '***cola***** one. Bare in mind that right now i have scaled in the plan to 1 instance. Do you require for me to change that?

Comment: @AlexandrosMylonas, Sorry for reply you later. I recommend you could check this blog to improve your site performance:http://prmadi.com/nodejs-app-performance-tweaks-azure-app-services-windows/ Any result, please let me know.